# Execute the code but delay the 'return' of a function in JS

Tags: javascript, return, delay

Am I able to, and if so how, delay the return of a Javascript function?

For example, say I use JS to set the background of an element that employs CSS3's transitions, and that transition takes 1 second, I'd like to `return` the function after the transition has finished (after 1 second).

Something like this (pseudo code):

```
function
    element.style = 'background: #aaa; transition: all 1s ease-in;' // this will take 1 second to transition, although the JS is executed immediately

    after 1 second // delay the return until the CSS3 transition completes.
        return element
```

I hope this all makes sense! Thank you in advance, your help is much appreciated!

It might be helpful for everyone to see the actual code too: http://jsfiddle.net/BtNSs/1/

Comment: In short, you don't (it's not that you can't make scripts wait, but in JavaScript for the web, you should not do that, and as Andy E said, the browser may run in the same thread as the UI). Instead, you have a function called at the end of the transition. JavaScript in the browser and even server-side JavaScript apply an asynchronous architecture. The browser will even warn if your script takes too long to run without returning.

Comment: Oh, just so everyone knows, the transition would actually only last 1/3 of a second... I just used 1 second in this example for brevity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're not able to do this.  In browsers, JavaScript and the UI share the same thread, so the animation will not begin until your JavaScript code finishes executing.

If you want to do something after the animation completes, use the [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition) event.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to delay the return. You want to execute a callback after one second.

```
function (element) {
    element.style = 'background: #aaa; transition: all 1s ease-in;' 

    setTimeout(function () {
      // whatever you wanted to do with the element;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Ideally, as @AndyE points out, you don't do it "after one second", but when the `transitionend` event occurs. This is more flexible and generally the right thing to do. Cross-browser support for that event is not yet soild, though. Depending on what you want to achieve, "after one second" might be *a lot* easier to implement.

Comment: I do want to delay the `return`. `element` is returned at the end of every function so I can 'chain' the functions (like chaining in jQuery). As soon as `element` is `return`ed the next function would fire, so I need to delay the `return`. If this absolutely can not be done I'll have to use callbacks. Thanks for your input on this!

Comment: @Jonathon No, you want to delay the firing of the next function. You are dealing with asynchronous work here, you must stop thinking in synchronous terms. Asynchronous functions *always* return immediately. This is a good thing. You do not work with return values, you always work with callbacks. jQuery does that the same way.

Comment: In jQuery you can chain effects like `$('#el').fadeOut().fadeIn()` can't you? How does jQuery handle only firing `.fadeIn()` once `fadeOut()` has completed? This is the sort of thing I need basically! Thanks again for your help, I do get what you're saying!

Comment: @Jonathon: jQuery has an effects queue. When you call `fadeOut().fadeIn()`, the appropriate functions are placed on the queue and called one after another (this is handled internally, with callbacks). If you want to react to the completion of `.fadeOut()`, for example, you must pass a callback as an argument. Unless you use your own jQuery queue (which you can do, no problem), you must do the plumbing (i.e. callback management) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

How about supplying a callback to the function, and executing that callback after the required amount of time.

```
function doSomething(callback){
  // execute your transition

  setTimeout(callback,1000);
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/eAMXK/ - you'll see it output the current time to the console, then a second later do the same.